# Error for syncdb while installing openstack

Tags: dashboard, openstack

I've seen other people say they have this error from openstack also, but I have not been able to find any kind of answer.

I followed the website http://uksysadmin.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/ for the base installation of openstack, and this seems to work correctly.

Now I'm following the website http://wiki.openstack.org/OpenStackDashboard  to install openstack Dashboard and when I get to the command "tools/with_venv.sh dashboard/manage.py syncdb"  I get this error:

```
ERROR:root:No module named local.local_settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harlan/horizon/openstack-dashboard/dashboard/settings.py", line 126, in <module>
    from local.local_settings import *
ImportError: No module named local.local_settings
ERROR:root:No module named local.local_settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harlan/horizon/openstack-dashboard/dashboard/../dashboard/settings.py", line 126, in <module>
    from local.local_settings import *
ImportError: No module named local.local_settings
Error: No module named horizon.dashboards.settings
```

I'm doing the installation on Ubuntu 11.10 Server.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's not finding your local_settings.py file, make sure you did this step (documented on the wiki):

```
$ cd horizon/openstack-dashboard
$ cp local/local_settings.py.example local/local_settings.py
```

As an aside, the simplest way to get up and running with OpenStack is to use [DevStack](http://devstack.org).